# Issue with IE Compatibility after updates

Tags: 2013, javascript, error, internet-explorer, browser-compatibility

This is a common question but I never find the answer to my question.  After an IE updates or patch work within SharePoint it will sometimes knock out some users ability to see things on their SharePoint page.  What to them seems as a permission issue is not true.  Permissions never changed but they cannot see things on their page that they could see a week ago.  To fix the issue they add the site to the IE compatibility.  For those that know what to do this is a helpful solution.  Others this can be annoying.

Question Is there something that can be done after or before IE upgrades or SharePoint patch that can avoid this scenario from happening or that a user does not have to change the IE compatibility view? Maybe code change or upgrade modifications.

Another question What causes this to happen?

Answer (score 1):

Always recommended to add the site to the trusted list.

This need to be done only once and you are good to go with updates and no future issues.

Another option is to force compatibility in the master page using the `meta` tag

Comment: Thanks.  I forgot to mention it is a site listed on the trusted site already and this only happens to random users not all.